# how to give a custom name to hadoop output files

Tags: hadoop

I want the output files in the format as 2012117-part-r-00000. Basically I want the output file to have the date appended to it, so that I can arrange the files according to date. I looked at OutputFormat and FileOutputFormat, but it doesn't help my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found out for the new API, I can use [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html#addNamedOutput%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%29) and the method addNamedOutput()

Comment: is it possible to rename output files of Sqoop ?

Answer (score 5):

There is not much flexibility in the output file name of the MR job. Use the subclasses of the [MultipleOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html).

The [MultipleOutputFormat#generateFileNameForKeyValue](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html#generateFileNameForKeyValue%28K,%20V,%20java.lang.String%29) method has to be implemented, ignore the inputs to this method and return a string in the `date + -part-r- + mapred.task.partition` pattern. [mapred.task.partition](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Configured+Parameters) is an int, so it has to be pre-padded with 0's appropriately.

Comment: IS there no easy way, in one of the earlier releases I guess we had the option like FileOutputFormat.setOutputName(JobConf job, String name); Also, my reducer class is already extending Reducer, so it will be tought for me to extend another class.

Comment: I don't see that in the Hadoop API.

Comment: Ok, but as I mentioned my reducer class is already extending another class, can I include a static class and have that class extend MultipleOutputFormat and then call the class from somewhere?

Comment: See how PartitionByStationUsingMultipleOutputFormat is implemented in the [code](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920010388/ch06.zip) of the Hadoop - The Definitive Guide book. Would also suggest to go through a couple of tutorials or buy the book on Hadoop.

Comment: The example should help. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways for changing Output filename.

**1.** By using a Java class MultipleOutputFormat.

```
// job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job,“20180318”, TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class);
```

**2.** By Using

```
job.getConfiguration().set(“mapreduce.output.basename”, “20180318”);
```

Reference link: http://data-flair.training/forums/topic/in-mapreduce-how-to-change-the-name-of-output-file-from-part-r-00000

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by using Multiple Output Format in the Mapper/Reducer class. For example:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;
```

Create an object of MultipleOutputs in the Mapper/Reducer class.

```
private MultipleOutputs<Text, NullWritable> _multipleOutputs;
```

In the setup, you can do:

```
_multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<Text, NullWritable>(context);
```

and then, in the map/reduce method, you can do:

```
_multipleOutputs.write(new Text(whatever you want to emit),new Text(whatever you want to emit),"xyz-m");
```

This will give you file names like xyz-m-00000 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have date appended to output files then use
[MultipleOutputs Apache Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html)

Here is a sample code to get you acquainted:

```
MultipleOutputs<Text, Text> mos;

@Override
public void setup(Context context) {
    mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
}

private IntWritable totalCommits = new IntWritable();

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int Count = 0;
    for (IntWritable val : values) {
        Count += val.get();
    }
    totalCommits.set(Count);
    String[] keySplit = key.toString().split(",");

    mos.write(new Text(keySplit[1]), new Text(totalCommits.toString()),keySplit[0]);
}

@Override
protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    mos.close();
}
```

The **write** method should have parameters in this sequence : **key, value, filename**.
Key and Value type should be same as the type declaration in the first line of code and filename should be String. Please note you cannot give special characters like "-", ":" etc. in filename.